# Arcadia called me a Nord, even though I am a Breton

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After experiencing difficulties with a stuck loading screen in Skyrim, I had to force my PS3 to shut down. Thankfully my saved file wasn't completely screwed up in the process.

But after I loaded my save game, I travelled to Whiterun to get some ingredients from Arcadia. Once I interacted with her, I was shocked to hear her say "Maybe a hardy Nord like you doesn't need a cure-all, hmm? What about an invisibility potion?" This isn't right. I am a Breton. I really hope this doesn't have anything to do with corruption in my save file.

I would like to know if anyone else has experienced this issue. I don't want to be confused for a Nord throughout the rest of my Skyrim gaming experience.

Comment: More likely slip ups like these are indications that either the NPC or your character has dementia.

Comment: Probably just an oversight in the programming.  I am sure there's a RaceType property associated to your character and it probably looks like `RaceType.Breton` in the code.  Most code in the game probably goes like `"Maybe a hardy " + RaceType + " like you"`, but Arcadia probably has a bug that somehow defaults RaceType to Nord instead of actually checking your actual RaceType.

Answer (score 9):

She says that to everyone, including my High Elf.

One interpretation is that she didn't call you a Nord, she called you hardy like a Nord.  Bretons can be quite literal.

Comment: My character has also been called a he when she's a she. Not with Arcadia though, just other random NPCs. Perhaps it is an oversight by Bethesda?

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer Or perhaps you should trim that beard more often...

Comment: @Artless I don't believe dwarf is a race in Skyrim... :P

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer it is a race, you just can't play as them.

Comment: @Bravo840 My bad :-/.

Comment: Would like to confirm that she says this to everyone. She says this to my Dark Elf character, which breaks immersion as I imagined my character as a Dunmer who initially was from Cyrodiil, but then moved to Skyrim until he was caught and falsely accused of crimes against the Imperials.

Comment: @Bravo840 well, it's an extinct race... (though I'm sure there's one left somewhere that somebody will point out just to prove me wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This is a glitch since Arcadia doesn't have a dialogue for other races. This has nothing to do with corrupted save files really. You can fix this by downloading the [Skyrim Unofficial Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch).

> Arcadia will never call you a Nord if your race isn't a Nord

[Download here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/?)

Comment: @TrentHawkins I'll edit this.